# joomla article in rokbox popup without menus, etc

Tags: joomla

i am using joomla rocketTheme Chapelco and want to display an article in the rokbox popup but without the menus, footers, etc.  I just want the article contents.

I can get the article to display in the popup using link params data-rokbox as shown here

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=200" data-rokbox data-rokbox-elemnent="#rt-popupmodule" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Submit</a>
```

but this displays the article with the full site menus, footers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Appending `&tmpl=component` to the url should fix this:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=200&tmpl=component"
   data-rokbox
   data-rokbox-elemnent="#rt-popupmodule"
   class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Submit
</a>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333993/1983389 for more details.